# I want to support data storage offline mechanism for cordova (Android and iOS) mobile app

Tags: sqlite, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, offline-caching, offline-mode

1- I already have Rest API & Now I want to store all these data locally and for using offline usage but My requirement needs to store 20-30 MB data, Please suggest any good mechanism for achieving the same.
2- Whenever data change or modify on server will notify and sync that data and store synced data offline.
3- Also I have global search option on home page in that I want to search all the content whatever we have in offline storage or server (string data, images, videos).

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You can use SQLite

Comment: Please share few links if u have. also please let me know we can store and mange 30 mb or more data using SQLite also we can achieve sync mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There are several storage you can use with cordova which can achieve your request

- Local Storage (but its limited to 5MB in android and 2.5MB in IOS)
- Files by using `cordova-plugin-file` which its recommended when you have a large size of data
- SQLite Database `cordova-sqlite-storage` its the best solution if you can organize your data into a tables
- IndexedDB its a NoSql database in `HTML5`, but you have to test its size capacity